# Why doesn't ConcurrentQueue<T>.Count return 0 when IsEmpty == true?

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I was reading about the new concurrent collection classes in .NET 4 on [James Michael Hare's blog](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/Default.aspx), and the [page talking about `ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/02/10/c.net-little-wonders-the-concurrent-collections-1-of-3.aspx) says:

> It’s still recommended, however, that
>   for empty checks you call IsEmpty
>   instead of comparing Count to zero.

I'm curious - if there is a reason to use IsEmpty instead of comparing Count to 0, **why does the class not internally check IsEmpty and return 0 before doing any of the expensive work to count**?

E.g.:

```
public int Count
{
    get
    {
        // Check IsEmpty so we can bail out quicker
        if (this.IsEmpty)
            return 0;

        // Rest of "expensive" counting code
    }
}
```

It seems strange to suggest this if it could be "fixed" so easily with no side-effects?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let me show you an **overstating** example:

```
public bool IsEmpty
{
   get { /* always costs 10s here */  }
}

public int Count
{
   get { /* always costs 15s here, no matter Count is 0 or 1 or 2... */  }
}
```

If they implement the `Count` property like this:

```
public int Count
{
   get
   {
       if (IsEmpty) return 0;
       //original implementation here
   }
}
```

Now when the final Count is 0, it costs 10s(5s less than before!great!), but for those Count is 1/2/more, it costs more than before, because checking `IsEmpty` costs time! So the optimization is not a good idea, because `IsEmpty` takes time. It will be good if `IsEmpty` is reading from a field directly.

**EDIT** I checked the implementaion of both `IsEmpty` and `Count` via reflector, both are *expensive*. Obviously checking `IsEmpty` for 0 count only will reduce the average performance speed.

Answer (score 16):

`ConcurrentQueue<T>` is lock-free and uses spin waits to achieve high-performance concurrent access. The implementation simply requires that more work be done in order to return the exact count than to check if there are no items, which is why `IsEmpty` is recommended.

Intuitively, you can think of `Count` having to wait for a timeslice when no other clients are updating the queue, in order to take a snapshot and then count the items in that snapshot. `IsEmpty` simply has to check if there is at least one item or not. Concurrent `Enqueue` and `TryDequeue` operations are changing the count, so `Count` has to retry; unless the queue is transitioning between the empty and non-empty states, the return value of `IsEmpty` isn't changed by concurrent operations, so it doesn't have to wait.

I wrote a simple multi-threaded test app which showed that `Count` was ~20% slower (with both constant contention and no contention); however, both properties can be called millions of times per second so any performance difference is likely to be completely negligible in practice.

Comment: Thanks for the info, though this didn't really answer the question (I've updated the title to match the question I put in the body): Why doesn't (can't?) the implementation of Count have "if (this.IsEmpty) return 0;" to avoid this performance "gotcha"?

Comment: Maybe because slowing every call of Count by waiting potentially twice to speed up an edge case isn't wise.

Comment: @VirtualBlackFox Ofcourse, this makes total sense. If you post it in an answer I'll mark it, rather than the answer being hidden in a comment :-)

Comment: I'll leave my answer to the original question.

Comment: Was your test done with a queue that contained items, or an empty queue?  The advice to use `IsEmpty` rather than `Count` when practical would make sense even if `Count` performed just as fast as `IsEmpty` in those cases where the queue was, in fact, empty.

Comment: @supercat Sorry, I don't recall, and I'm not sure if I have the source code anymore to check.

Answer (score 1):

Understanding how concurrent structures work is very important.

`if (isEmpty()) ...//do whatever`

if you have concurrent structure the check is close to no-op since *everything* can change between isEmpty and any subsequent operation.

`Count` iterates through the nodes (have not used c# for almost 6 years, but the java analog does the same) to calculate, so it is an expensive call. 
**Straight answer**: Checking isEmpty before Count will incur additional memory fence and effectively achieve nothing.
Edit: if unclear. Count when the queue is empty costs exactly as isEmpty, however it costs a lot when the queue *is not*!

Count similar to isEmpty for concurrent structures has little to no meaning since the result of the call may not be useful and greatly changed.

Comment: I think you totally missed the point of the question. Writing code that uses IsEmpty and Count==0 has zero effect on concurrency, since all locking in these classes is internal. My question was about why the Count property couldn't quickly check IsEmpty internally rather than recommend to use IsEmpty.

Comment: @DanTup, it does have effect, and you have the answer, it costs a memory barrier (far from free). I didn't miss the point. Reread the answer.

Comment: @DanTup, added extra clarification, namely: if the queue isEmpty, count is not expensive (exactly as isEmpty), however it is otherwise

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood. I thought you meant when IsEmpty=true. When it's not, then you're right, Count would become more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

`IsEmpty` provides some thread concurrency that if you obtain the `Count` value and compare it, its on your thread, but the queue could be changed.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287100.aspx) says:

> For determining whether the collection
>   contains any items, use of this
>   property is recommended rather than
>   retrieving the number of items from
>   the Count property and comparing it to
>   0. However, as this collection is intended to be accessed concurrently,
>   it may be the case that another thread
>   will modify the collection after
>   IsEmpty returns, thus invalidating the
>   result.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "if you obtain the Count value and compare it, its on your thread". How is that different from calling IsEmpty, that's also on that thread.

Comment: This is exactly the same with Count. If I read Count and it returns 0, it could also be modified before my next operation. This doesn't explain why Count internally could not check IsEmpty and return 0 to avoid this "gotcha".

Comment: Or the other way around, that calling IsEmpty on the queue class (which is documented that Count is O(1)) could just use a Count==0 check.

Comment: @nos I think so too, but since it would've been easier to "optimise" this way than write about the gotcha, I wonder if there's actually a reason.

Comment: @DanTup - Danny Tuppeny  According to that page, Count is O(1), there is no mentioning of .Count == 0 being "slower" than IsEmpty. He just recommends that you use IsEmpty. Using IsEmpty will clearly state that you're checking for emptyness, and if they ever change the implementation of .Count in the future, your code calling IsEmpty will presumably still be optimized. And if your code is agnostic to the type of container, IsEmpty might be more efficient for containers where .Count is slower.

Comment: @nos The reason doesn't matter (slow/less efficient), the point was that it could be done for us, to make things easier. And anyone reading code should be able to figure out ".Count == 0" means "Is Empty" (in fact, I'd say the Count is clearer). I think VirtualBlackFox hit the nail on the head - it'd slow down other calls to Count.

Comment: Well, according to VirtualBlackFox , the reason is precicely because of slowness/less efficient - which is probably quite right , as otimizing count == 0 makes little sense when there's a very clear and precisely named IsEmpty method